# Inflating custom view in different process (Xposed)

Tags: android

I'm developing an Xposed-module and would like to use a custom view class (the class is rather complex, so I can't recreate it from scratch/only using system UI elements). As per [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48725716&postcount=7156) post by the GravityBox dev, it should be possible (albeit difficult). I've looked at the hint he posted ([BasicTile.java](https://github.com/GravityBox/GravityBox/blob/kitkat/src/com/ceco/kitkat/gravitybox/quicksettings/BasicTile.java)), but am unable to apply this to my situation.

I'd like to use the [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)-library in my module, which works fine if I use it as the content of my module's settings-activity (for example), but fails with a `ClassNotFound`-exception when it's used from the Xposed-bridge-process.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating the class in code (with a context created from your app's package) works (while inflating it from xml does not).

The way to make this work:
- Add an empty `<View>` placeholder in your xml (instead of the custom view itself)
- In your code, inflate the xml-layout
- Programmatically create an instance of your custom view class and add it as a child to the View placeholder:

`ViewGroup mContainer = (ViewGroup) yourInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.container);
YourCustomViewClass mCustomView = new YourCustomViewClass(context);
mContainer.addView(mCustomView);`