# Get xml View or Context from Xposed Module

Tags: android, android-context, android-inflate, xposed-framework

I'm developing a Xposed module, I've searched and I haven't found the answer.

But I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869535/inflate-layout-in-xposed-module) and I don't know how/what `getObjectField()` work/need, and also I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037172/inflating-custom-view-in-different-process-xposed) but it need my app context. I can get a context from the system but I need to get a view from my exposed module and inflate/add it in some part of the system UI and I don't know how I can do this.

To be clear:

- Get the context of my module application activity(?).
- Create an inflater with my module context that can catch a view of a layout of my module.
- Put this view by `hookLayout()` (I know how to do this).

Does Xposed provide a easy way to get views from my module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My xposed module "SnapColors" does all this and is open source you can take a look at the source.

Github SnapColors: https://github.com/Programming4life/SnapColors

**Module context:**
You shouldn't do this some devices have security restrictions which prevent you from doing this, instead take a look at "Layout Inflating:" section but never the less here's how to do it.

```
Context moduleContext = AndroidAppHelper.currentApplication().createPackageContext("yourModulePackageName", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

Source: [createPackageContext (String packageName, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int))

**Layout Inflating:** https://github.com/Programming4life/SnapColors/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/manvir/SnapColors/TextureLayout.java#L34

**hookLayout Example:**
https://github.com/Programming4life/SnapColors/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/manvir/SnapColors/App.java#L73

Comment: also i've found here , but thx for the explanation XD https://github.com/EliteChoob/XposedRecentTasksRAM1.1-src/blob/master/src/ro/brucelee/xposed/recenttasksram/ModClearAllRecents.java